# How is the process from compiling a c/c++ code to executing it?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, system

I'm a student of computer science and I have a couple of questions related to the process of compiling a c/c++ code. One question is, when you compile, does it get compiled to assembler or machine code? At the same time, is this assembler/machine code a version for the operating system? The reason of my last question is that when you compile, your program can be executed in different cpus in the same operating system. Apart from that your program can't be executed in another operating system. This make me wonder what there is in the executable you generate for an operating system and what the operating system do with it in order to execute it in different cpu. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: The first step is deciding which language you want to use (There is no language called C/C++. C and C++ are two different languages).

Comment: A proper answer would require at least one entire textbook. Short version: (1) It ultimately becomes machine language. Whether the compiler emits assembly language and feeds that to a separate assembler program, or directly emits machine language, is an implementation detail of the compiler and you don't need to worry about it. (2) Some details of the generated machine language do depend on the operating system, but the CPU is much more important. Most of the time, all of the CPUs in one computer are the same _kind_ of CPU, so a program can run on any of them without modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about some basics of the process.
The compilation process is illustrated nicely in section 1.6 here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html

Your compiled code will be for a specific operating system and cpu architecture.
Read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251250/why-do-executables-depend-on-the-os-but-not-on-the-cpu

Comment: Thank. The first link made me understand not only more about the compile process but also more about static and shared libraries.